# Decoding json data in Python

Tags: python, json

This is my json data,

```
{
  "Chromatic Dragon": "D",
  "Croesus": "@",
  "Cyclops": "H",
  "Dark One": "@",
  "Death": "&",
}
```

This is the code that I'm using to decode this into a dict,

```
import sys, json
d = json.loads('mapping.json', encoding='utf-8')
print(d)
```

I'm expecting the variable d to be a dict

However this is the error that I get,

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.loads` loads a string. You'll want to open a file, and read that using `json.load`.

```
import sys, json
with open('mapping.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f, encoding='utf-8')
    print(d)
```

Although you'll also want to take off that trailing comma from your JSON file for it to be parsable by python.

Answer (score 0):

The [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)  will load your json if it was a string such as...

```
json = "{
  "Chromatic Dragon": "D",
  "Croesus": "@",
  "Cyclops": "H",
  "Dark One": "@",
  "Death": "&",
}"
```

If you want to load an external json file, use **json.load()** instead.

So your code would be...

```
import sys, json
with open('mapping.json') as json_file:
    d = json.load(json_file)
print(d)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `string` types are not readable as file-like objects.